# Multiple checkmark accessory not working properly in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableview which lists options which the user can choose to filter another list by. When an item in this tableview is clicked a checkmark shows up and if it is clicked again the checkmark disappear. The user is allowed to click multiple tableview cells to show a checkmark on many of the cells at the same time. The tableview is also divided into sections.

This all works fine on iOS 8 but when I run this on iOS 7 the checkmark doesn't show up when I click on the cell. If I go to another view and then back to to tableview the checkmark is there. I have searched other posts on stackoverflow which suggest I should try and set the tint color of the cell to black, which I have tried which doesn't work.

I have also replaced the checkmark with a custom cell with a checkmark image which I unhide and hide. Here the checkmarks shows when I click them, but when I click them again it doesn't go away. I will attach the code bellow for clarity.

```
@property NSMutableArray *favorite;
@property NSMutableArray *favoriteCheckmark;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filtercell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [favorite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([favoriteCheckmark containsObject:indexPath]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        break;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
FilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filtercell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [favorite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([favoriteCheckmark containsObject:indexPath]){
            [favoriteCheckmark removeObject:indexPath];
        }else{
            [favoriteCheckmark addObject:indexPath];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive, but this might have something to do with it:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
FilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filtercell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [favorite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([favoriteCheckmark containsObject:indexPath]){
            [favoriteCheckmark removeObject:indexPath];
        }else{
            [favoriteCheckmark addObject:indexPath];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

You're calling:

```
FilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"filtercell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

On did Press, which is queing a new cell, and might be causing problems.  Try removing that line and see what happens.

**Note**

Even if this doesn't solve your problem, you should remove that line.  There's no purpose it could serve in its current placement.

Comment: Plus, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method there is no reloadData call to update the UI to match the newly updated model.